# When to create client id and secret for an API,during Login or Registartion?

Tags: java, spring, api, authorization, client

I am creating an API and there are multiple clients,So I am implementing a client id-secret artitechure.My questions are:

- When should I create the client id and secret? during registration of Login?
- How should I connect users to respective client ids?
- How should I store client ids and secret?

Comment: you need to check JWT based authN and authZ. Generate and return JWT for every successful Login and include JWT validation method to verify the user against JWT for subsequent logins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the client id and secret ( client credentials in OAuth2) use to communicate between server and server ( because secret key stored in server web, where secure with anyone want to access without permission), if for user web I refer you use authorization code flow
- each client have a client id (unique per resource)
- store in the table with client id, password (encode by md5, ...), role, scope, ... and using it to verify, then create a new token for the client. the client will use a token to request your API, just use secret when need refresh token or create a new token

Comment: So here's my flow:
I register in the api,that creates a client id and secret for the client along with username and password.
I then go to login screen,I login and using the user details i fetch the client id and secret and return it with a successfull response.
After that in all the subsequent requests I use that client id and secret to authorize?

Comment: @HimanshuRanjan if you use stateless you don't need the form login. just send the username and password encoded with each request in header param Authorization: Basic user:password. And if you use statefull, after verify username and password success you return the session to user, and user send the session with each request.